# In unite gallery how to stop video when click on close button of modal box

Tags: video, gallery

I have called unite video gallery in bootstrap modal box. while closing modal video is still playing in background how to stop that?

Answer (score 0):

Its easy I found Solution

```
$('#interactive-3d').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
   $('#printer-gallery video').each(function ()
    {
     this.pause();
   });
});
```